# ubuntu server 14.04 port 21 keeps closing

Tags: 14.04, server, ufw

I have got a problem with port 21, which keep closing.

I am using `proftp` and `ufw` and set port 21 to internal network only. This works fine, however, after a few hours or days (not sure on time limit), port 21 is not accessible anymore. The only way to use it again is to reboot server and it then works fine. Unfortunately, after some time I'm back to the same problem.

Comment: When it stops working on port 21, does any kind of error get presented to you?  As well, where you're running proftp, when it 'stops working', does `sudo netstat -tlpn | grep :21` show anything listed still?

Comment: Hi I have just been looking and I have found it is proftpd had stopped. Restarted and it is working again. so the problem is proftpd stopping? any fix?

Comment: Start by checking the syslog when it stops working, see if there's any log of any event - `dmesg | grep proftpd`

Answer (score -3):

It's not exactly a solution, but you probably don't need to reboot you computer, just try to restart your networking service! Your software may be causing some exceptions to occur on your machine, that will later block the port!

When that happens again try this!

```
sudo service networking restart
#sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart #the old fashioned way
```

The above will restart your networking interfaces!

Comment: `iptables` isn't a service that can be started and stopped.  This answer won't help the user.

Comment: You are right, in debian/ubuntu there is no service/shortcut to restart iptables. I have edited my answer i removed the iptables section. That applied to CentOS... Sorry for the trouble, and thank you for pointing that out! I really did thought that it applied to all distributions out there...

Comment: The bigger concern is `sudo service networking restart` won't solve the port 21 being 'closed' issue on its own - it is better to identify what is actually happening than to assume the networking is causing it - it could be the kernel killing the ftp program, for instance.

Comment: True, i rest my case here...